# Is there any difference in com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container Class between version 2.3.15.3 to 2.3.16

Tags: struts2, xwork

I think in Earlier version(before 2.3.16) `org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer` can cast to `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container`. After it it give following error....

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] to required type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container] for property 'container'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] to required type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container] for property 'container': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:329)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:183)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:42)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] to required type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container] for property 'container': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Post configuration files.

Comment: Seems some project dependency problem. Check your pom. Maybe some hints at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927262/struts-2-3-16-1-upgrades-giving-typemismatchexception-for-struts-xwork-and-simpl ( Also please upgrade to 2.3.16.1 !)

Comment: Ya it is a same kind of problem,Also same kind of configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration of bean file earlier..

```
.............
.............
<bean id="container" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
    <property name="destination" ref="requestQueue" />
</bean>
.............
.............
```

It have to change like bellow

```
.............
.............
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
    <property name="destination" ref="requestQueue" />
</bean>
.............
.............
```